# Javascript solution for huge size value multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a web application where I need to allow to the users to select one or more values I'm usig Jquery 1.11 I was think to use a picklist and not an autocomplete mainly for the following reason: it's not sure that users know what they want to add; they may want to select what to add by seeing a list The problem I'm facing is that in my database I can have thousands of values and a picklist showing all these elements is not comfortable to use I was wondering is there is some kind of Javascript library who can offer to me a paged picklist Otherwise.... what is the best way to show this huge size of data? By taking care that users often don't know what they can add

My situation is the following one: in my project i'm using a WCM (Liferay) and I'm doing some extension to the redactional side of contents. I must provide to the user to fill a field by selecting 1 or N (with N>1) other web contents taken from WCM DB

Often redactors don't use tags and/or categories when they write web contents and some web contents can be written from some user groups and others web content can be written by others user groups; virtually each user group don't know/communicate with other user groups and this means that each user don't know what other user adds so I can't use some autocomplete solution

At the beginning I'll have few Web Contente, but after some time, by seeing the old web site, i can reach huge values (around 4000/5000 web contents and also more)

I already used select2 and I like it, but I have only two option for select2:

1. full load all data from DB but this means to kill performances and
   show users all the data in a combobox
2. offer a search to users but users may not know what to search and so
   they can do a lot of research without finding what they are looking
   for

Now I was seeing also this JQuery plugin: https://github.com/yanickrochon/jquery.uix.multiselect but this plugin doesn't offer pagination options so I should always load all data from DB

I'm wondering if I can use some kind of Javascript utility to solve my issue or if I should take another kind of solution

If I should use another kind of solution.. what would be the best one?

I premise that this form will be only used on the redactional side and so I don't need a multi-device solution

Comment: Have to go through thousands of values to see which ones might be applicable, is annoying for the user, no matter if the data is paginated or not.

Comment: You may need to find a way to group and filter your data, so that your users can narrow down what they want. No matter what you do, thousands of entries is nothing a user can reliably handle at once, and unless the gain from the exercise is on the extreme side, noone ever will.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/lucknerjb/PaginationSelect

Couldn't find a verified project, however this one seems legit. 
If you download zip and run index.html you will see this widget at work.

However personally I would rather implement some sort of server side user cart and download items range from a database dynamically instead of serving entire list of items to the user at once.

Comment: thank you; implementing a server side solution instead of loading the full DB list is my target too; what I need is to understand what is the most comfortable way for the user; i'll give a look to the suggested plugin

Comment: @AngeloImmediata imho the most comfortable way is to have a list of clearly defined and differentiable categories, inside of it paginated list of selectable items, some kind of filtering/searching capability would be very helpful. Other nice idea is having two lists: items and selected items. Once a user selects a single item from items list, it is moved to selected items list.

Comment: Also it would be unfortunate and quite irritating if I would select lets say couple hundreds of items which will than accidentally deselect. You should make an effort to remember user selection at least between page reloads as they happen very often.